# What are "p" and "r" wrt the moon?

Tags: the-moon, moon-phases

Still learning, thinking - and failing - about the moon.

timeanddate.com has this cute and dynamic moon sketch at e.g. https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/uk/london

[image]

They generate this based on three parameters that they call `i`, `p` and `r`. The above image is the result of invoking this: https://www.timeanddate.com/scripts/moon.php?i=0.028&p=3.388&r=0.035.

I know that `i` stands for *i* llumination in the range 0-1.

However, what are `p` and `r` and in what unit? What are the likely correct terms? `r` appears to be some sort of "rotation angle" of the moon while `p` is the same for the "mask".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to crack this.

`i` = illumination

`p` = rotation of the "mask" (i.e. shadow) = bright limb angle + π/2 - parallactic angle

`r` = rotation of the moon = position angle of axis - parallactic angle

(all angles in radians)

Computational sources for programmers:

- Java: https://bitbucket.org/talonsoalbi/sunmooncalculator/src/master/SunMoonCalculator.java
- C++: https://github.com/ThingPulse/esp8266-weather-station/blob/master/src/SunMoonCalc.cpp
- Python: https://github.com/bokepasa/SunMoonCalculator

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the are angles in radians. With "i=0.5" to make things clearer:

- $p=0$ is the right half illuminated
- $p=\pi/2=1.57$ is top half illuminated  (rotated anticlockwise by 90 degrees)
- $p=\pi=3.14$ is left half illuminated  (rotated 180 degrees)

and so on.

The r parameter is the rotation of the moon, so $r=0$ is "lunar north up" $r=pi/2$ is rotated anticlockwise by 90 degrees.

Comment: Thank you for explanations. I use a piece of software that provides a plethora of moon (phase) properties for a given timestamp and location. "axis position angle", "bright limb angle" and "paralactic angle" don't mean much to me yet but I will analyze them and try to understand which ones relate to the above.